# VisualForce in Professional Edition

Tags: visualforce, professional-edition

A client's Professional Edition org does have a (limited) Developer Console in it. I do know PE supports Visualforce. If I go into Setup and create a VF page there, I can save it just fine. However if I try to update the same page in Developer Console I get the error *Can't alter metadata in an active org*.

Now this is just strange, because Visualforce pages are never subject to this message in other orgs - only Apex. Moreover, even if PE supports sandboxes now, it has no Change Sets which means you still do have to edit Visualforce directly in the production org. Is Developer Console just the wrong tool to use for this in PE?

Comment: Presumably you need to use the deployment tool to push the changes using the metadata api.

Comment: Well the org definitely allows me to edit Visualforce pages in production, just not if I try to use Dev Console for it. Is there a specific restriction that explains this?

Comment: This may be an issue with the Tooling API. The legacy Visualforce editor in setup uses a customized version of the Metadata API to save your changes. This API difference is likely the reason you see the error in one location and not the other. If you decide to use the Force.com IDE or Mavensmate you can choose which API you want to compile with.

Comment: I see. So Dev Console saves Visualforce using an API that Professional Edition doesn't support, but doesn't know how to give correct error messages that the issue is due to PE's limitations.